# has anybody installed CartoPY on macOS?

Tags: python, cartopy

I am trying to install cartoPy on macOS using pip, but always run into errors, can anybody help me with this?

I use pip install cartoPy (no syntax errors, it's just to get the test to display here.)

Comment: What are the errors? Please [edit] to post the exact commands you used and the exact error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install Anaconda (didn't want to ) and now I have it. It seems like the only way to get the mapping lib, ...